# Compiz uses 80-85% of CPU while idle

Tags: 13.04, intel, ubuntu-netbook

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 earlier. Installation went on smoothly but after I successfully installed it, it became so sluggish! I checked it using system monitor and found out that Compiz uses 80-85% while idle but the memory it uses doesn't surpass more than 20%.

My netbook's specs:
Intel Atom N2100 (1.6ghz x 2), Intel GMA 3150, 2GB of ram.

I disabled all effects and animation using unity-tweak-tool and CCSM but I don't see any improvement in performance. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Reset your BIOS settings. This happened to me too.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But what specific option should I change in my BIOS? Sorry for the question again.

Comment: I loaded all BIOS settings to default/optimal values... it worked for me.

Comment: You say Compiz takes high CPU usage by using **top** command ryt??